# Error 420: paraView not found, after typing in 'paraFoam' in terminal [OpenFOAM]

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, paraview, openfoam

I have lately installed OpenFoam v.2212.0 on UBUNTU 22.04.0. All the other OpenFoam commands work fine for me, but as soon as I type "paraFoam", I get the following error:

---

```
Invalid $PV_PLUGIN_PATH and -plugin-path= not defined

No supplementary ParaView/OpenFOAM reader modules

Using builtin reader: paraFoam -vtk

Created temporary 'damBreak.foam'

/usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/bin/paraFoam: 420: paraview: not found
```

---

Installation Path: */usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/bin/paraFoam* (I have navigated myself there using terminal commands and it is there where it needs to be)

Command typed in '.bashrc' prior to installing as per installation instructions:

*source /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/etc/bashrc*

I am new user of Ubuntu Linux and would be very grateful if someone can direct me to a possible fix.

Comment: You need to install Paraview separately.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded paraview from the web and also had this error.

These are steps that I had followed:

1. Delete paraview
2. Type `sudo apt-get install paraview` in ubuntu terminal

With these steps, after meshing with `blockMesh`, typing `paraFoam` works perfectly.